# Should I flag these questions?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

All of these questions are the same, two asked by the same person and the third has the same code so i assume the same person there too. Does this qualify to be flagged?

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185043/how-to-track-and-follow-a-person-using-kinect
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184993/kinect-show-a-message-when-the-user-is-moving
3. [How to detect what direction the user is walking in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183296/kinect-how-to-mention-what-direction-the-user-is-walking)

Comment: Shoot first, ask questions later

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same guy trying to get around a question ban with another account.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'm sure since the same code is provided on all of the questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag one of them and include an explanation and links to the other two.

Also, they're all "Not a Real Question" so they should all be closed.